# Converting the following C# sample to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

This is the sample in C#

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(jsonText);

Console.WriteLine(dict["some_number"]); //outputs 108.541
```

For I keep getting errors when I try to use an online converter to convert it to vb.net.  Does anyone know how to rewrite this in vb.net?

The error I get from http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ is:

```
-- line 3 col 1: EOF expected
```

Comment: What output do you get from the converters, and what are the errors that you get?

Comment: I get `-- line 3 col 1: EOF expected` from: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: That isn't a valid C# program, hence why the converter throws up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to put in valid C#.

I changed your input code to the following:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class Test {

   public void DoSomething() {

      var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(jsonText);

      Console.WriteLine(dict["some_number"]); //outputs 108.541

   }
}
```

Then passed it through [developer fusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to get:

Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

```
Public Class Test

    Public Sub DoSomething()

        Dim jss = New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(jsonText)

        Console.WriteLine(dict("some_number"))
        'outputs 108.541
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need some form of class in the file as currently your variables are being created outside of a class. Splitting the `using` apart as this should be at the top of the file I think that following should work:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
```

The rest is:

```
Dim jss = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String,String))(jsonText)

Console.WriteLine(dict("some_number")) 'outputs 108.541
```

You also don't declare `jsonText` so I would not expect this code to run as it is. I have not tried to compile this but it looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Dim jss = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(jsonText)

Console.WriteLine(dict("some_number"))
'outputs 108.541
```